# Show that these two differential equations have the same solution

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

**Question:** Show that the problems $ax'' + bx' + cx = f(t); x(0) = 0, x'(0) = v_0$ and $ax'' + bx' + cx = f(t) + av_0 \delta(t); x(0) = x'(0) = 0$ have the same solution for $t \gt 0$. Thus the effect of the term $av_0 \delta(t)$ is to supply the initial condition $x'(0) = v_0$.

The first thing I notice is that these two differential equations involve a few initial values, so naturally I approach the problem using the Laplace transform. I begin with the first equation: $$ax'' + bx' + cx = f(t)$$ becomes $$a(s^2 X(s) - v_0) + bsX(s) + cX(s) = F(s) \rightarrow as^2 X(s) - av_0 + bsX(s) + cX(s) = F(s)$$

Solving in terms of $X(s)$ yields $$X(s) = F(s)G(s) + av_0 G(s)$$ where $G(s) = \frac{1}{as^2 + bs +c}$. I then take the inverse Laplace of this equation to get $$x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(\tau)g(t - \tau) d\tau + av_0 g(t)$$

I do the same for the second equation, $ax'' + bx' + cx = f(t) + av_0 \delta(t)$, but end up with $$x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(\tau)g(t - \tau) d\tau + av_0 u(t - a)g(t - a)$$

From here I am unsure about what to do. I have two *distinct* values for $x(t)$, yet I am supposed to show that the two have the same solution? Have I made any errors? What do I do now? Also, what is the intuition behind the very last sentence, specifically that "the effect of the term $av_0 \delta(t)$ is to supply the initial condition $x'(0) = v_0$"?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of an ambiguity in the problem statement. If $ax^{\prime\prime}+bx^{\prime}+cx=f(t)+av_0\delta(t)$ it implies that $x^{\prime}(t)$ has a jump discontinuity of height $\Delta x^{\prime}=\frac{av_0}a=v_0$ at $t=0$. Thus $x^{\prime}(t)$ is undefined at $t=0$ so it makes more sense to talk about what happens at $t=0^-$ just before the jump discontinuity and $t=0^+$ just after.

In the first differential equation, the question of what $x(t)$ looks like for $t<0$ is moot because the initial values of $x(t)$ and $x^{\prime}(t)$ are given. In the second we are going to assume that for $t<0$, $x(t)=0$ and replace $f(t)$ by $f(t)u(t)$ with the unit step function $u(t)$ turning on the driving function at $t=0$. Then
$$\begin{align}x^{\prime}(0^+) & =\int_{-\infty}^{0^+}x^{\prime\prime}(t)dt=\frac1a\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\left(-bx^{\prime}(t)-cx(t)+f(t)u(t)+av_0\delta(t)\right)dt\\
 & =\frac1a\left(-0-0+0+xv_0\right)=v_0\end{align}$$
and
$$x(0^+)=\int_{=\infty}^{0^+}x^{\prime}(t)dt=0$$
because $x^{\prime}(t)$, $x(t)$, and $f(t)$ are bounded near $t=0$. Both systems have the same driving function, $f(t)$, for $t>0$ and they have the same conditions at $t=0^+$, so they must have the same solutions.

Comment: I have a few questions, sorry if I am not too keen on the subject.

1. **How do you know that $x'(t)$ has a jump discontinuity of height $\Delta x'$ at $t = 0$?**

2. **I'm still unclear about the intuition behind your process in evaluating $x'(0^+)$, including where you are getting those integrals, and how you are able to change the bounds on the integrals from $\int_{-\infty}^{0^+}$ to $\int_{0^-}^{0^+}$. **

3. **In order to prove that two systems have equivalent solutions, do we just need to know whether or not they are bounded and have equivalent conditions near a certain point?**

Comment: If $x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t\delta(u)du$ then you know that if $t<0$, then $x(t)=0$, while if $t>0$, then $x(t)=1$. That's a jump discontinuity, and the fundamental theorem of calculus would indicate, perhaps sketchily, that $x^{\prime}(t)=\delta(t)$. I changed the bounds because $\int_{-\infty}^{0^-}x^{\prime\prime}(t)dt=0$ by design. If two second-order systems have the same two initial conditions and the same differential equation that dictates how the solutions propagate forward in time, they will stay the same given a deterministic mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Second equation:
$$
ax'' + bx' + cx = f(t) + av_0 \delta(t)
$$
$$
as^2X(s) + bsX(s) + cX(s) = F(s) + av_0 \cdot 1
$$
$$
X(s) =F(s)G(s) + a v_0 G(s)
$$
$$
x(t) = f(t)*g(t) + a v_0 g(t)
$$
So they are the same.

---

1) You should check a laplace transform table $\delta(t) \leftrightarrow 1$

Whether you are using Bilateral or unilateral definition
$$
\int_{-\infty \mbox{or}0}^{\infty} \delta(t) e^{-st} dt = e^{0} = 1
$$

2) $x(t) = ... + av_0 u(t - a)g(t - a)$ what's even the "$a$" in the $t-a$ ????

Comment: The "$a$" denotes the shift in the unit-step function.

Comment: For the first part of your answer I'm a bit confused. It seems that you reached the same conclusion as I have, but the problem lies in showing that $x(t) = f(t) * g(t) + av_0 g(t)$ is equivalent to the solution of the other differential equation $x(t) = f(t) * g(t) + av_0 u(t-a)g(t-a)$, where $*$ denotes convolution.

Comment: ??????????????? Read again carefully, I started with your second equation. (The one that you supposed to arrive to $x(t) = ... + u(t-a)g(t-a)$ )

Comment: There's no shift .... the shift comes when you have something like $F(s) e^{-as}$ then you have $f(t-a)$ but is not the case here.

Comment: What I have showed is that starting with the second equation I arrive to the solution of your first equation, meaning that they have the same solution

Comment: The whole answer aims to show that you that you can't arrive to $x(t) = ... + av_0 u(t - a)g(t - a)$  in the second equation

Comment: I asked what's even the "$a$" in the $t−a$ ???? because there's no way (in that equation/context) that a constant suddenly shows up as an argument.  $\mathcal{L}(f(t)) = F(s) \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(kf(t)) = kF(s)$ then $\mathcal{L^{-1}}(kF(s)) = kf(t)$

Comment: Because $\mathcal{L}^{-1} (e^{-as}G(s)) = u(t-a)g(t-a)$

Comment: ??????? and where does $\mathcal{L}^{-1} (e^{-as}G(s))$ shows up for the second equation. It doesn't. My answer shows the way to solve for the second equation which leads to the same solution as the first equation.